# Fast way to remove bits from a ulong

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

I want to remove bits from a 64 bit string (represented by a unsigned long). I could do this with a sequence of mask and shift operations, or iterate over each bit as in the code below. Is there some clever bit-twiddling method to make this perform quicker?

```
public ulong RemoveBits(ulong input, ulong mask)
{
    ulong result = 0;
    ulong readbit = 1;
    ulong writebit =1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {   
        if ((mask & readbit) == 0) //0 in the mask means retain that bit
        {
            if ((input & readbit) > 0)
            {
                result+= writebit;  
            }
            writebit*=2;
        }
        readbit *= 2;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I need to perform `RemoveBits` millions of times in a performance critical scenario.

It's probably too abstract to help, but the number of distinct masks used, while not known at compile time, is determined early at runtime (before the performance critical bit), and is likely to number fewer than 100. Essentially, I'm using the bitstring to represent an `n-tuple`, and `RemoveBits` projects onto an `m-tuple` `(m < n)`.

Comment: What language? If this is too abstract to be limited to a language, it might fare better on the "Computer Science" SE site.

Comment: So you want to remove all bits in `input` that are also set in `mask`? Then try `input & ~mask`.

Comment: @Gumbo - I don't just want to zero a bit, I also want to right-shift any bits to the left of it.

Comment: @Conduit. I'm using C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as [compress right](http://programming.sirrida.de/bit_perm.html#c_e). Unfortunately, there isn't really a great way to do it without special hardware support (which exists as [pext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets#Parallel_bit_deposit_and_extract), rather new). Here are some ways given in Hackers Delight, modified to be in C# and for 64bit `ulong`s, but not tested:

```
ulong compress(ulong x, ulong m) {
   ulong r, s, b;    // Result, shift, mask bit. 

   r = 0; 
   s = 0; 
   do {
      b = m & 1; 
      r = r | ((x & b) << s); 
      s = s + b; 
      x = x >> 1; 
      m = m >> 1; 
   } while (m != 0); 
   return r; 
}
```

This has the benefit of having far fewer branches than the code in the question.

There's also a way with far fewer loop iterations, but far more complicated steps:

```
ulong compress(ulong x, ulong m) {
   ulong mk, mp, mv, t; 
   int i; 

   x = x & m;           // Clear irrelevant bits. 
   mk = ~m << 1;        // We will count 0's to right. 

   for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      mp = mk ^ (mk << 1);             // Parallel prefix. 
      mp = mp ^ (mp << 2); 
      mp = mp ^ (mp << 4); 
      mp = mp ^ (mp << 8); 
      mp = mp ^ (mp << 16); 
      mp = mp ^ (mp << 32);
      mv = mp & m;                     // Bits to move. 
      m = m ^ mv | (mv >> (1 << i));   // Compress m. 
      t = x & mv; 
      x = x ^ t | (t >> (1 << i));     // Compress x. 
      mk = mk & ~mp; 
   } 
   return x; 
}
```

Comment: What I posted is more or less the second version with the `x`-independent computations hoisted out.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I'll take your word for it, it looks complicated

Answer (score 1):

The bit twiddling hacks site doesn't have this particular operation, though it has [the one that inspired this answer](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#InterleaveBMN).

The idea is to compute, offline, a list of magic numbers that can be plunked into the following template. The template consists of a basic step repeated 6 = lg 64 times: rectify the indexes of the output bits mod 2**k for k = 1, 2, ..., 6, assuming at the start of each step that the indexes are correct mod 2**(k-1).

For example, suppose that we wish to transform

```
x = a.b..c.d
    76543210
```

into

```
....abcd
76543210.
```

Bit `a` is at position `7` and needs to go to `3` (correct position mod 2). Bit `b` is at position `5` and needs to go to `2` (incorrect position mod 2). Bit `c` is at position `2` and needs to go to `1` (incorrect position mod 2). Bit `d` is at position `0` and needs to stay (correct position mod 2). The first intermediate step is to move `b` and `c` like so.

```
a..b..cd
76543210
```

This is accomplished with

```
x = (x & 0b10000001) | ((x >>> 1) & 0b00010010);
         //76543210                 //76543210
```

Here `>>>` denotes a logical shift and `0bxxxxxxxx` denotes a big-endian binary literal. Now we're left with two problems: one on the odd-indexed bits and one on the even-. What makes this algorithm fast is that these now can be handled in parallel.

For completeness, the other two operations are as follows. Bit `a` is now at position `7` and needs to go to `3` (correct position mod 4). Bit `b` is now at position `6` and needs to go to `4` (incorrect position mod 4). Bits `c` and `d` need to stay (correct positions mod 4). To get

```
a....bcd
76543210,
```

we do

```
x = (x & 0b10000011) | ((x >>> 2) & 0b00000100);
         //76543210                 //76543210
```

Bit `a` is now at position `7` and needs to go to `3` (incorrect position mod 8). Bits `b`, `c`, and `d` need to stay (correct positions mod 8). To get

```
....abcd
76543210,
```

we do

```
x = (x & 0b00000111) | ((x >>> 4) & 0b00001000);
         //76543210                 //76543210
```

Here's some proof of concept Python (sorry).

```
def compute_mask_pairs(retained_indexes):
    mask_pairs = []
    retained_indexes = sorted(retained_indexes)
    shift = 1
    while (retained_indexes != list(range(len(retained_indexes)))):
        mask0 = 0
        mask1 = 0
        for (i, j) in enumerate(retained_indexes):
            assert (i <= j)
            assert ((i % shift) == (j % shift))
            if ((i % (shift * 2)) != (j % (shift * 2))):
                retained_indexes[i] = (j - shift)
                mask1 |= (1 << j)
            else:
                mask0 |= (1 << j)
        mask_pairs.append((mask0, mask1))
        shift *= 2
    return mask_pairs

def remove_bits_fast(mask_pairs, x):
    for (log_shift, (mask0, mask1)) in enumerate(mask_pairs):
        x = ((x & mask0) | ((x >> (2 ** log_shift)) & mask1))
    return x

def remove_bits_slow(retained_indexes, x):
    return sum(((((x // (2 ** j)) % 2) * (2 ** i)) for (i, j) in enumerate(sorted(retained_indexes))))

def test():
    k = 8
    for mask in range((2 ** k)):
        retained_indexes = {i for i in range(k) if (((mask // (2 ** k)) % 2) == 0)}
        mask_pairs = compute_mask_pairs(retained_indexes)
        for x in range((2 ** k)):
            assert (remove_bits_fast(mask_pairs, x) == remove_bits_slow(retained_indexes, x))
test()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good site that has been around for a long time called [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).  It has a number of fast algorithms for bit manipulation.  One you might want to look at (and I am copying verbatim here, this is not my own work) is this algorithm:

> **Conditionally set or clear bits without branching**
>
> ```
> bool f;         // conditional flag
> unsigned int m; // the bit mask
> unsigned int w; // the word to modify:  if (f) w |= m; else w &= ~m; 
>
> w ^= (-f ^ w) & m;
>
> // OR, for superscalar CPUs:
> w = (w & ~m) | (-f & m);
> ```
>
> On some architectures, the lack of branching can more than make up for
>   what appears to be twice as many operations. For instance, informal
>   speed tests on an AMD Athlon™ XP 2100+ indicated it was 5-10% faster.
>   An Intel Core 2 Duo ran the superscalar version about 16% faster than
>   the first. Glenn Slayden informed me of the first expression on
>   December 11, 2003. Marco Yu shared the superscalar version with me on
>   April 3, 2007 and alerted me to a typo 2 days later.