# Bitwise operations to remove specific bits expressed as a mask

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

As part of a serial data protocol decoder, I must decode data that has sync bits inserted (bits that are not part of the data and are always '1'). I need to remove the sync bits and assemble the data by shifting the remaining bits left. Each 32-bit word has a different pattern of sync bits. I know what the patterns are, but I cannot come up with a generalized was of removing the sync bits.

For example, I might have a bit pattern like this (just showing 12 bits for example):

> `0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1`

I know that some of those bits are sync bits, specifically those that are '1' in this mask:

> `0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1`

The resulting data should be those data bits with a '0' in the corresponding mask, shifted to remove the sync bits, padded right with zeros. The mask above could be understood as "take first 2 bits, skip next 2 bits, take next 4 bits, skip next bit, take 2 bits, skip 1 bit".

E.g I should end up with:

> `0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0`

Trying to do this in Java but I don't see any bit mask/shift operations that would make this work.

---

Best method I could come up with (does not left align the results, but that is OK for my purposes):

```
private static final int MSB_ONLY = 0x80000000;

private static int squeezeBits(int data, int mask) {
    int v = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<32; i++) {
        if ((mask & MSB_ONLY) != MSB_ONLY) {
            // There is a 0 in the mask, so we want this data bit
            v = (v << 1) | ((data & MSB_ONLY) >>> 31);
        }
        else {
            // Throw bit away
        }
        mask = mask << 1;
        data = data << 1;
    }

    return v;
}
```

Comment: You aren't going to be able to do this with bitwise operations alone.  You're basically going to need a loop to construct the output bit-by-bit (although you may be able to leverage lookup tables or equivalent to improve things).

Comment: Updated this with the best (looping method) I could come up with...

Comment: You can do it based on `pext`, which Java doesn't expose but it [can be emulated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25492730/555045), though the emulation is kind of bad - possibly no better than just doing it the obvious way