# Bit selection algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I want to find an efficient way to select bits from one stream using the bits of another stream in C. The amount of data processed is terabytes, so speed is important.

What a "bit selector" does is select only certain bits from out of a sequence of bits. For example, if the source stream is [ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 ] and the selection criteria is [ 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ] then the result will be [ 1, 0, 1 ].

An example of doing this the following:

```
uint64_t source[5];
source[0] = 1234567890987654321;
source[1] = 3456789098765432198;
source[2] = 5678909876543219876;
source[3] = 7890987654321987654;
source[4] = 9098765432198765432;
uint64_t selector[5];
selector[0] = 8214263800482614621;
selector[1] = 4251759498365531188;
selector[2] = 1628009771533217836;
selector[3] = 6890182644227957152;
selector[4] = 3018964452491735032;
size_t count_values = 5;
uint64_t result[5];

size_t xCurrentResultBits = 0;
uint64_t result_value = 0;
size_t result_index = 0;
for( size_t xSelector = 0; xSelector < count_values; xSelector ){
   uint64_t current_selector = selector[ xSelector ];
   uint64_t current_source = source[ xSelector ];
   for( size_t bit = 0; bit < 64; bit++ ){
      uint64_t mask = 1;
      mask = mask << bit;
      uint64_t selector_value = current_selector | mask;
      if( selector_value > 0 ){ // keep the bit in the source
         uint64_t source_value = current_source | mask;
         result_value = result_value << 1;
         if( source_value > 0 ) result_value = result_value + 1;
         xCurrentResultBits++
      } else {
         // throw away source bit
      }
      if( xCurrentResultBits == 63 ){ // filled up a result value
         result[ result_index ] = result_value;
         result_index++;
         result_value = 0;
         xCurrentResultBits = 0;
      }
   }
}
```

The problem is that this method is probably a lot slower than it could be. Is there a well-known algorithm to do this fast?

Comment: What does this algorithm do? For example `selector_value = current_selector | mask;` always non-zero, so next `if` looks strange

Comment: It looks like it might be calculating `*selector & *source` in a really convoluted way. See [bitwise and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_AND_.26) to check if that's what you meant.

Comment: Where this data is coming from? Probably from some IO channel. Which is much slower than your algorithm. So I wouldn't worry about it until profiled and proven it is a bottleneck.

Comment: `mask << bit;` expression has no effect.

Comment: Rather than dump a bunch of dense code on us and expect us to understand what problem you're trying to solve, explain it to us *in words*. What you've done here is akin to showing me a tool that does a job I'm not familiar with, and asked me to help you design a similar tool to do something that you haven't even defined.

Comment: Please before optimizing the code, check if your algorithm works at all. This is very unlikely with errors like the one mentioned by @wildplasser [`mask << bit;`]

Comment: @JimMischel I explained what a bit selector is for those people who do not know what it is. I did not do this originally because anyone who does not already know what a bit selector is would be unlikely to be able to answer the question.

Comment: I know what a bit selector is. Your "explanation" of a bit selector is, at best, incomplete. Somebody who doesn't know what one is wouldn't be able to figure it out from those two sentences. And the code you provide is way more complicated than it needs to be to illustrate the concept. In any case, my suggestion, as it is for most things, is to first write something that works, *then* figure out how to make it fast.

Comment: @JimMischel I am not interested in optimizing my algorithm. The question is whether there is a BETTER algorithm altogether. I included my first attempt, simply to illustrate the general idea of what is being done. I expect that an efficient algorithm will work in a completely different way, so the nuances of my toy algorithm are irrelevant.

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25492730/555045)?

Comment: @harold Yes, thanks harold. harold, once again a lone island of wisdom in an ocean of ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it byte by byte and based on a lookup table.

Create a lookup table that gives you the bit patterns to be or'ed (after shifting) onto the current and the next byte of the output. This table is indexed by [sourceByte][selectorByte], so it's a 256*256 table of byte values.

Shift the table result by the number of bits already occupied in your current output byte, and OR that onto the current and next byte (or maybe use bigger chunks for the result).

Advance the output bit position and byte pointer by the number of bits from the selector byte (another table byte[256] might be easier than bit-fiddling).

But in the end, you have to profile the program and try which approach is faster (and if the bit-fiddling really makes for a noticable portion of the run-time).